# Is Perlin Noise a "fractal"?

Tags: fractals, noise

I have an old Spanish CG book that calls Perlin Noise a "fractal structure". After reading [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) I couldn't deny it or confirm it. Is it a fractal structure? What would it Hausdorff dimension be?

Comment: Since there has been no reply, can you explain what you mean by "fractal structure".
I suppose that if you think about it in terms of increasingly becoming less noisy, it may be a fractal.

Comment: I mean self-similar on multiple scales. Is this fractal noise?

Comment: it is statistically self similar. That is a type of fractal.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider two types of fractals: deterministic of an iterative structure (like a Kantor's set) and stochastic which is self-similar in law. If a Perlin noise is a stochastic noise? Then you should verify if there exist a rescaling such that it preserves the distribution law.

On the other hand, the term "fractal" is not formalized, so you can use it for any "self-similarity".

Comment: here is a discussion on a similar topic. http://www.fractalforums.com/general-discussion-b77/could-pi-be-considered-a-fractal/15/